# If I discern Minor Illusion, does it become transparent?

Tags: dnd-5e, illusion

The [*minor illusion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/minor-illusion) spell uses the following rules in the last paragraph of the spell description for how a creature determines whether or not the illusion is actually an illusion:

> If a creature uses its action to examine the sound or image, the
>   creature can determine that it is an illusion with a successful
>   Intelligence (Investigation) check against your spell save DC. If a
>   creature discerns the illusion for what it is, the illusion becomes
>   **faint** to the creature.

What is unclear to me is the meaning of "faint". English not being my first language I checked the dictionary and what I understand is that my object will be blurry, out-of-focus, looking fake… but it will still be there. On the other hand, my GM has ruled it is simply transparent for whoever looks at it (context was putting a 5-ft-by-5-ft black box in front of a window to block the view).

**Does seeing through an illusion make it transparent?**

Comment: Related: [When Silent Image Is Disbelieved, Is It Transparent?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/76916) (likely not a duplicate because the spell uses different wording for what happens when the illusion is discerned)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Yes

> [Faint: (of a sight, smell, or sound) barely perceptible.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/faint)

If something is barely perceptible, you will only just be able to see it. At a glance, you could miss it. This would not be true if the illusion remained opaque, so it makes sense that it would be transparent once you discern it for what it is.

From a gamist perspective, your question notes one of the main uses of Minor Illusion - to block vision. If the object remained opaque, in a lot of cases succeeding on that check would provide no benefit to an enemy.

Comment: As a side note, making the illusion faint is important for tactical reasons. You're still aware of the effect, and can even do neat things with it: if your party wizard has created a 5x5 cube, and you know it's not real, you can hide in it and attack from inside it. Provided your opponents haven't seen through the illusion, you can see your opponents, and they can't see you. Lovely! If the spell became completely invisible to you, though, you wouldn't know when it ended (and you may want to move once it's over!).

Comment: It can also be fun to put various things that are triggered by looking at them behind an illusory wall and then wait for someone to realise it's an illusion.

Answer (score 6):

## It can probably be seen through.

We can compare *minor illusion* to the very similarly worded 3rd-level *major image*:

> A creature that uses its action to examine the image can determine that it is an illusion with a successful Intelligence (Investigation) check against your spell save DC. If a creature discerns the illusion for what it is, the creature can see through the image, and its other sensory qualities become faint to the creature.

This spell uses the exact same mechanic as *minor image* for discerning the nature of the illusion, and it also describes the illusion as becoming faint after being discerned. It also explicitly says the image can be seen through.

These are two different spells, spells do only what they say they do, and just because one spell behaves in a particular way doesn't mean a similar spell also does. However, in this particular case it looks like the intent is that a *minor image* can be seen through once it has been discerned for what it is. Otherwise, the *minor illusion* cantrip would be more effective at vision-blocking illusions than a similar 3rd-level illusion spell, which would be an odd design.

Beyond that, we have nothing to go on besides the word "faint," which leaves it up to a DM ruling based on the definition of the word. (Other answers have covered this.) I've also avoided using "transparent" or "translucent" in this answer, since those can be subjectively interpreted. For mechanical purposes, it's sufficient that an illusion "can be seen through."